# Asterisk how to dynamic allocate sip account to ip phone

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-ari

I am new in Asterisk field. I am facing a situation.
I have 10 sip accounts and 20 clients (softphones), so how to dynamic allocate those sip account to those clients?
Is there any best practices in the case?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is just add 10 more sip phones.

All other variants are adminstrative  like not allow user X register fomr 10am to 10pm and have no any relation to asterisk.

Please note, sip device != extension. You can have more sip devices then extensions if your dialplan support that.